# Find all paths through a tree (nested dicts) from top to bottom

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary, tree

**EDIT:** See below for a suggested answer and how it's not quite right yet.

*There are many similar questions to this one on Stack Overflow, but none exactly like it in Python. I'm a programming novice, so please go easy.*

I have a tree of nested dictionaries, like this:

```
[{'word': 'The',
  'next': [{'word': 'End',
            'next': None},
           {'word': 'quick',
            'next': [{'word': 'brown',
                      'next': [{'word': 'fox',
                                'next': None}]}]},
           {'word': 'best',
            'next': [{'word': 'of',
                      'next': [{'word': 'times',
                                'next': None}]}]}]}]
```

I want to flatten all paths from top to bottom and end up with this:

```
[[{'word': 'The'},
  {'word': 'End'}],

 [{'word': 'The'},
  {'word': 'quick'},
  {'word': 'brown'},
  {'word': 'fox'}],

 [{'word': 'The'},
  {'word': 'best'},
  {'word': 'of'},
  {'word': 'times'}]]
```

I made a lovely little recursive function that created the original structure in the first place, but I'm having a hard time unrecursivizing it. This is as far as I got:

```
def flatten_combinations(result_tree, current_combo = None, all_combos = None):
    if current_combo is None:
        current_combo = []
    if all_combos is None:
        all_combos = []
    if result_tree is None:
        all_combos.append(current_combo)
        return
    for word in result_tree:
        current_combo.append({'word': word['word']})
        flatten_combinations(word['next'], current_combo, all_combos)
    return current_combo
```

…which returns this:

```
[{'word': 'The'},
 {'word': 'End'},
 {'word': 'quick'},
 {'word': 'brown'},
 {'word': 'fox'},
 {'word': 'best'},
 {'word': 'of'},
 {'word': 'times'}]
```

…which is clearly somewhat close, but not quite right.

I know that function is probably horribly un-Pythonic, but I'm teaching myself programming, so I'm not even trying to take advantage of possibly-existent language features that would let me elide over thinking through this stuff from scratch (*” he said, posting to a Q&A site in the hope its members would help him elide a bit of thought*).

So: what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Moshe below corrected a couple of problems:

```
def flatten_combinations(result_tree, current_combo = None, all_combos = None):
    if current_combo is None:
        current_combo = []
    if all_combos is None:
        all_combos = []
    if result_tree is None:
        all_combos.append(current_combo)
        return
    for word in result_tree:
        current_combo = current_combo[:]
        current_combo.append({'word': word['word']})
        flatten_combinations(word['next'], current_combo, all_combos)
    return all_combos
```

This is closer yet, but not quite right:

```
[{'word': 'The'}, 
 {'word': 'End'}],

[{'word': 'The'},
 {'word': 'End'},
 {'word': 'quick'},
 {'word': 'brown'},
 {'word': 'fox'}],

[{'word': 'The'},
 {'word': 'End'},
 {'word': 'quick'},
 {'word': 'best'},
 {'word': 'of'},
 {'word': 'times'}]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two minor mistakes in that:

1) You return `current_combo` instead of `all_combos`. That only gives you your last result

2) On each **iteration**, you modify `current_combo`. Make a copy first!

```
new_current_combo = current_combo[:]
new_current_combo.append({'word': word['word']})
flatten_combinations(word['next'], new_current_combo, all_combos)
```

Full code:

```
def flatten_combinations(result_tree, current_combo=None, all_combos=None):
    if current_combo is None:
        current_combo = []
    if all_combos is None:
        all_combos = []
    if result_tree is None:
        all_combos.append(current_combo)
        return
    for word in result_tree:
        new_current_combo = current_combo[:]
        new_current_combo.append({'word': word['word']})
        flatten_combinations(word['next'], new_current_combo, all_combos)
    return all_combos
```

Comment: Close, but no cigar; I've added a bit about the results of this function above. (I haven't even tried to further fix it myself yet.)

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in a copy of current_combo on the recursive call then you won't lose your current path on the next iteration of your for loop.

Also, you don't need to return current_combo since the result isn't used in recursion.  You might want to return all_combos instead and not take it as a parameter.  Alternatively, you could have a recursive function and none recursive function, with the no-recursive function creating the list for all_combos and passing it into the recursive function so that the recursive function could assume all_combos was set.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take this strategy: For each tree,

1. Recurse to compute the list of sentences that come after the word at the root of this tree.
2. For each sentence, prepend the current word in front of it.
3. Return the newly-extended list of sentences.

Have you done proofs by induction? I find induction to be one of the most useful math techniques in my programming:

1. Prove that your function correctly handles a tree where 'next' is `None`.
2. Prove that your function handles a tree of depth `n`, assuming it can correctly handle a tree of depth `n-1`.

Induction then extends the proof to cover trees of any depth. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Just making @JoshHeitzman's answer concrete (and simplifying your default params):

```
def flatten_combinations(result_tree, current_combo = [], all_combos = []):
if result_tree is None:
    all_combos.append(current_combo)
    return
for word in result_tree:
    current_combo.append({'word': word['word']})
    flatten_combinations(word['next'], current_combo[:], all_combos)
return all_combos
```

Comment: Passing in a list as a default argument is bad! See the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)