# Flattening nested list (again)

Tags: python

I'm trying to flatten a nested list (actually a bunch of commands with some branches depending on True or False results). I need to build from such a bunch a simple list of linear "pipes" to run.

Anyway, here is a basic example:

```
[0, 1, ['T', [2, 3, ['T', [4], 'F', [5]]], 'F', [6, 7]], 8]
```

I wish to get:

```
[[0, 1, 'T', 2, 3, 'T', 4, 8],  
 [0, 1, 'T', 2, 3, 'F', 5, 8],
 [0, 1, 'F', 6, 7, 8]]
```

I tried to derive [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354080/find-all-paths-through-a-tree-nested-dicts-from-top-to-bottom), and went to this:

```
def _flatten(commands, pipeline=None, queue=None):
    global loop
    if pipeline is None:
        pipeline = []  # new pipeline started
    if queue is None:
        queue = []
    for com in commands:
        if not hasattr(com, '__iter__'):
            pipeline.append(com)
        else: #new list
            new_pipeline = pipeline[:] # keep existing root
            _flatten(com, new_pipeline, queue)
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    queue.append(pipeline)
    return queue
```

I'm not so far, since my results are:

```
[[0, 1, 'T', 2, 3, 'T', 4],
 [0, 1, 'T', 2, 3, 'T', 'F', 5],
 [0, 1, 'T', 2, 3, 'T', 'F'],
 [0, 1, 'T', 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 'T', 'F', 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 'T', 'F'],
 [0, 1, 8]]
```

Comment: It is not at all clear to me from your example what your rules for deriving the output from the input are. Your input structure seems somewhat suspect, I think dictionaries `{True: ..., False: ...}` might be better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools` for the most of iterator's operations.

flatten you will get using `itertools.chain`

```
>>> import itertools
>>> itertools.chain.from_iterable(listOfLists)
```

You will get more [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) in docs.